# ipc - shm - will string remain in memory until system reboot?

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

`"abc"` string was stored to shared memory.

The program has finished (quit) by    `return 0;` but the string is still stored in memory.

- How long will it remain there?
- Will it remain there until system reboot?
- Can it be relied on that it will remain there?

Relevant code:

```
int main() {

    int mem_id;
    key_t key;
    char * string;

    key = 01;

    int str_len;
    str_len = strlen("abc") + 1;

    mem_id = shmget(key, str_len, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    string = shmat(mem_id, NULL, 0);

    strcpy ( string, "abc" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shared resources are usually reference-counted.  When the count is decremented to 0, the resource is freed.

Comment: This is the default behavior of shared memory. To control various possibilities look at `shmctl` function.

Comment: You shouldn't probably be using SysV shared memory for anything new in 2017, use the [POSIX shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) instead

Comment: System V IPC is kernel persistence. That is a kernel-persistent IPC object exists until either it is explicitly deleted or the system is shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string will remain there until another process overwrites it or deletes the shared memory segment, or the system is rebooted.

See also [`man ipcrm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcrm.1.html) for removing shared SysV resources from the command line.